# Where can I find the status of the VSTS high fidelity database migration tool?

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

What is the status of the "option 3" migration tool mentioned in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/adopting-vsts and where can I monitor said status? I've read it was planned for 2016q2 and it is almost end of q3 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft usually responds to new features through UserVoice and looks like they should be providing an update soon, see:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2264946-import-data-from-tfs-on-prem-into-vs-team-services